# Uniformly continuous function implies almost Lipschitz continous.

Tags: epsilon-delta, uniform-continuity, lipschitz-functions

I wrote a proof of the following exercise but I am dubious there may be an incorrect step in it. I would appreciate your comments:

If $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^m$ is uniformly continuous on $D\subset\mathbb{R}^n$, then for all $\epsilon>0$ exists $K>0$ such that $||f(x)-f(y)||\leq K||x-y||+\epsilon$ for all $x,y\in D$

$\text{Proof:}$

Let $\epsilon > 0$. Since $f$ is uniformly continuous on $D$, there is $\delta > 0$ such that, if $||x-y||<\delta$, then $||f(x)-f(y)||<\epsilon$.

Define $K:=\frac{1}{\delta}>0$. Then, for all $x,y\in D$:

$K||x-y||=\frac{1}{\delta}||x-y|| \iff ||x-y||<\delta \text{   }... (1)$

Then: $||f(x)-f(y)||<\epsilon\text{   } ... (2)$

Adding $(1)$ and $(2)$ we get:

$$||f(x)-f(y)||<K||x-y||+\epsilon$$

$\square$

Is this proof correct? I have seen this exercise with an extra hypothesis: namely that $D$ is convex or compact.

Comment: Since $K\|x - y\| = \frac{1}{\delta}\|x - y\|$ is an identity, the statement $K\|x - y\| = \frac{1}{\delta}\|x - y\| \iff \|x - y\| < \delta$ does not make sense. So the proposed solution goes wrong from then on. Is it assumed that $D$ is compact?

Comment: It's true for _convex_ $D$; the proof of that makes me suspect it's false as stated, although a counterexample might be complicated